# Navigating to Marker when clicked OSMdroid Android

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I've just written some code to set the onclick listeners for all markers on my map (I want to navigate to a marker when I click it). However the method doesn't seem to be working - in fact I popped a few Toasts in for debugging and they don't seem to be printing either. Would appreciate some input on what I'm missing... I just call navigateToMarkers in onCreate().

```
//method to set onclicks for markers - when you click one, you navigate to it.
private void navigateToMarkers(){
     for(int i=0; i<bookMap.getOverlays().size(); i++){
        if(bookMap.getOverlays().get(i) instanceof Marker){
            ((Marker) bookMap.getOverlays().get(i)).setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                    DrawRoad drawRoad = new DrawRoad(getCurrentLocation(), marker.getPosition());
                    drawRoad.execute();

                    Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Marker clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }


}

//we do this in a different thread as it takes some amount of processing power to get route to ucd.
private class DrawRoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Road> {
    GeoPoint startPoint;
    GeoPoint endPoint;

    public DrawRoad(GeoPoint startPoint, GeoPoint endPoint){
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected Road doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(MapActivity.this);

        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
        waypoints.add(startPoint);
        waypoints.add(endPoint);

        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

        return road;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Road road){
        updateUIWithRoad(road);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, it should work.

Which osmdroid version used?

When debugging, can you check you reach the line:

```
((Marker) bookMap.getOverlays().get(i)).setOnMarkerClickListener(
```

Comment: Anyone help on this? In Oncreate(), I believe that adding the markers to map has taken X amount of time (working in the background on an ASyncTask). When I call the method navigateToMarkers() after addMarkers(), it immediately starts working even though the markers have not yet been added to the map. How to make the method navigatetomarkers() only start after markers have been added?

Comment: Of course, if you start an asynctask to create markers, and immediately after you call navigateToMarkers(), your markers will not be created yet! Don't add markers in an AsyncTask !!!